# Python zip behavior with *

Tags: python

Why there is the following result with zip function (example number 3):

```py
l = list(zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b']))
print(l)
# [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')] - ok, zip works as expected

l = list(map(lambda t: t[0] + t[1], zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b'])))
print(l)
# ['1a', '2b'] - nice, I have expected result with argument passed as tuple

l = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, *zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b'])))
print(l)
#['12', 'ab'] - Why?! I just added * and it broke everything?
```

Moreover, if I type:

```py
l = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, *zip(['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])))
print(l)
```

I get the followint error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    l = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, *zip(['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])))
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: As the error says, *zip outputs three elements. On the other hand lambda function takes two, x and y

Comment: But list(zip(['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])) gives me: [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')], two items on each step, not three items.

Comment: `*` means to unpack the list, which when you unpack the resulting list, gives you *three items*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start with this iterator:

```
map(lambda x, y: x + y, *zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b']))
```

Where you use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to "transpose" the lists:

```
zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b']) -> [('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')]
```

That means `map` effectively receives this:

```
map(lambda x, y: x + y, *[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b')])
```

Which is [equivalent](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to:

```
map(lambda x, y: x + y, ('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'))
```

A [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with more than one iterable takes an element off each of them and passes them into the function, so the result is:

```
[(lambda x, y: x + y)('1', '2'), (lambda x, y: x + y)('a', 'b')] == ['12', 'ab']
```

I don't know where your confusion comes from, but this should help. Please check out the documentation linked for further details.

Comment: Oh, I understand - I completely misused behavior of * in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
l = list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, *zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b'])))
print(l)
```

output:

```
['12', 'ab']
```

Here `*zip(['1', '2'], ['a', 'b'])` returns two tuples `('1', 'a') ('2', 'b')` (notice there are no comma in between both tuple which means they are both got unpacked due to the `*` operation)

the lambda function concatenates the first element of each tuples as when you pass multiple iterable items to a `map` function it just iterates over both iterable simultaneously!
On each iteration it takes one element from each tuple and concatenates.

Similar to the first one, the expression returns `*zip(['1', '2', '3'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` three tuples `('1', 'a') ('2', 'b') ('3', 'c')` hence, in each loop `map` just iterates over all three tuples and thus gets three 
 arguments.